proof of limits involving infinity using formal definition
I am reading my lecture notes on limits and stumbled across a 'solved' example problem.
It concerns with the limit of $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} (x - \sqrt{x + 1}) = \infty
$$
Using the formal definition of $ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty $, as $ \forall A > 0, \exists M > 0  \textrm{ such that }  x > M \implies f(x) > A $
My lecturer has given $M = A^2$ as a possible M, without justification.
I am having difficulty in finding this, from considering $$ x - \sqrt{x+1} = \frac{x^2 - x - 1}{x+\sqrt{x+1}} $$
Thanks for any ideas.

Hi. Always the degree leads the increase so your fraction tends to infinity. Another way to see this is factoring $x$ and verify that $\dfrac{x-1-\frac 1x}{x+\sqrt{x+1}}$ tends to $1$

Adding one more way to previous comment: show, that reciprocal tends to zero.

Yeah. Thanks for the suggestion. I understand the intuition behind this, but I’m struggling on formalising this.

Let's add some observations that will lead us to more formality showing our function $f$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

We can rewrite $f$ as $f(x) = \frac{x-1-\frac{1}{x}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}}$

Additionally we know $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}$ tends to $0$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$ (good practice to prove this). Convergence allows us, for a defined/chosen (tolerance of) $\epsilon:=1$, to pick $N>1$ such that if $x>N$ then $0<\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}<1$.

So, for this (beautiful) $N$ chosen (in step 2) if $x>N$ then we know the following with respect to order:$$f(x) = \frac{x-1-\frac{1}{x}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}}> \frac{x-(1+\frac{1}{x})}{1+1}> \frac{x-2}{2} $$ (Note: Since $x>N>1$, we know $1+\frac{1}{x}<2$)

We can argue a few ways; (i) "Hit it with an order-hammer": Since $\frac{x-2}{2}\rightarrow+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$ combined with the inequality in step 3, we know $f(x)\rightarrow+\infty$. (ii) "Using the definition": For any given $A$,  $\frac{x}{2}-1>A$ if and only if $x>2A+2$. Therefore (as we want the bound in step 2 as well as $\frac{x}{2}-1>A$) we define $M:=\max\{N, 2A+2\}$. Now, if $x> M$ will get us $f(x)>A$


Like much of analysis, we can (and should) formalize our observations into a proof:

Since $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}$ tends to $0$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$. Pick $N>1$ such that if $x>N$ then $0<\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}<1$.
Fix $A>0$ and define $M:= \max\{N, 2A+2\}$
Suppose $x > M$, then (i): $x>2A+2$, so $\frac{x-2}{2}>A$; and (ii): $x>N$ so $0<\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}<1$
Therefore, if $x>M$ we have the following: $$f(x) = \frac{x-1-\frac{1}{x}}{1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}}> \frac{x-(1+\frac{1}{x})}{1+1}> \frac{x-2}{2} >A $$

So, we've shown that for any $A>0$, there exists a $M>0$ such that if $x>M$ then $f(x)>A$. Therefore $f$ tends to $+\infty$ as $x\rightarrow+\infty$.  I hope this helps with showing the formality in this and future problems in real analysis!

Hey DrAychEmm, I understand your proof thank you! I am trying to prove the 'lemma' in your comments that $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}}$ tends to $0$ as x goes to positive infinity. For all $\epsilon > 0$, let $M = \frac{2}{2\epsilon -1}$, such that for $x > M = \frac{2}{2\epsilon -1}$ implies $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}} < \sqrt{\frac{(2\epsilon -1)^{2}+4\epsilon-2}{4}} = \sqrt{\frac{4\epsilon^{2}-1}{4}} = \sqrt{\epsilon^{2}-0.25}< \epsilon$ Is it correct?

Hi Omega, you are most welcome! I am so glad you like the proof; speaking of which, your lemma looks great (to help you verify: Notice you proved via definition): Keep up the hard work!
